# MATLAB - create a loop to read from text variables and assign it to variables and then perform in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, variables, matrix, read-text

I'm really new to Matlab and I'm currently working on it to create some matrixes. 
i need to write a loop that reads a text file then assign each set of integers to a variable with a certain number for example # of the row. after that it will perform some calculation and then finally Concatenate the arrays in matrix 1xn but what i got stuck with is the process of reading the file and then assign it to a dynamic variable then increment the counter. 
i think i have the correct logic with the pseudo code for it but I'm struggling with the actual syntax in MATLAB to be able to do it.

somewhat mix of pseudocode & actual code i managed to write:

```
content= fopen('text file.txt');

for i=1:size(content,1) *%loop to read till the end of the matrix* 

    variable_part(i) = fgetl(fid); *%read row and create the integer value in the dynamic variable.*

    for i=1 *% loop through the matrix that contains all the created dynamic variables one by one and perform these.* 
         for i=1:size(variable_part(i),1)
             a= variable_part(i)(i,:);
                variable_part(i,1)= mean(a);
                variable_part(i,2)= min(a);
                variable_part(i,3)= max(a);
                variable_part(i,4)= std(a);
                variable_part(i,5)= var(a);
                variable_part(i,6)= max(a)-min(a);
          end;
     end;
end;
```

so that fo example the result will be as follows:

```
content = (27*1) matrix.

%First loop 
for i=1:size(content,1) *%loop to read till the end of the matrix* 
variable_part1 = 4835:5551; *%first variable created and was assigned with the value of the first row. 
%Second Loop 
      for i=1 %in the matrix that contain all the variables created in the first loop 
%Third loop
 for i=1:size(variable_part1,1)
                 a= variable_part1(1,:);
                    variable_part(1,1)= mean(a);
                    variable_part(1,2)= min(a);
                    variable_part(1,3)= max(a);
                    variable_part(1,4)= std(a);
                    variable_part(1,5)= var(a);
                    variable_part(1,6)= max(a)-min(a);
              end;
         end;
    end;
```

i know the results for the third loop is working and producing what i want but my issue is in the Read text file and the first 2 nested loops.

i appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and the result you would like to achieve?

Comment: for example the text file has these numbers where each one of them has a separate row 89896:94645, 129992:133476, 152262:152323, 189803:197131...etc  and after it reads it it will assign it the variable names "Part1_Frames", "Part2_Frames", "Part3_Frames", "Part4_Frames" ...etc until the end of file. after that it will perform the above calculations on every variable "Part1_frames_calculation" "Part2_frames_calculation" .. hope i explained it clearly

Comment: Still not very clear, no... but you're on the wrong track if you're trying to create 'dynamically named variables'. Store your intermediate data in a suitable format such as a cell array, struct array or table - look each of those up in the MATLAB help for more information.